# Zorich Exercise 5.7.3: Reduction of integrals of the form $\int R(x,\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})\,dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

> Consider integrals of the form
> $$\int R(x,\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})\,dx,\tag{1}$$
> where $R$ is a [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) of $x$ and $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$. Show that the integral $(1)$ can always be reduced to computing integrals of the following three types:
> $$\int \frac{P(x)}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}\,dx,\qquad \int\frac{dx}{(x-x_0)^k\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}},\qquad \int\frac{(Ax+B)\,dx}{(x^2+px+a)^m\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}.$$

This is an exercise in Zorich's [Mathematical Analysis I](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-48792-1) textbook, chapter 5, section 5.7.

My attempt: Assume that $R(x,y)=\frac{P(x,y)}{Q(x,y)}$, where $P, Q$ are polynomials. We write
$$P(x,y)=P_1(x,y^2)y+P_2(x,y^2),\qquad Q(x,y)=Q_1(x,y^2)y+Q_2(x,y^2),$$
where $P_1, P_2$ and $Q_1, Q_2$ are all polynomials. Then
\begin{align*}
R(x,\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})&=\frac{P_1(x, ax^2+bx+c)\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+P_2(x, ax^2+bx+c)}{Q_1(x, ax^2+bx+c)\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+Q_2(x, ax^2+bx+c)}\\
&=\frac{F_1(x)\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+F_2(x)}{G_1(x)\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+G_2(x)},
\end{align*}
where $F_1, F_2, G_1, G_2$ are polynomials.

And I'm stuck here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for your comment and the interesting link. But I cannot find anything useful to my problem in that wiki page. The integral considered in this post is not an elliptic integral: The wiki page starts with $\int R(x, \sqrt{P(x)})dx$, where "$P$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ or $4$"; but in this post $P$ is a quadratic polynomial. So they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
\begin{align}
\frac{F_1(x)\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+F_2(x)}{G_1(x)\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+G_2(x)} = \frac{F_1(x)\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+F_2(x)}{G_1(x)^2(ax^2+bx+c)-G_2(x)^2}(G_1(x)\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}-G_2(x))
\end{align}